# I am trying to call aws nodejs SDK describeStacks (cloud formation) to get details of the stack. I am getting an error. Code and response given below

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

**I am trying to call aws nodejs SDK describeStacks (cloud formation) to get details of the stack. I am getting an error. Code and response given below.**

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 var awscred = {
     accessKeyId: "******************",
     secretAccessKey: "*****************",
     region: "ap-southeast-1",
     sslEnabled: false
 };



        /*=======METHOD TO DESCRIBE STACK================*/


    exports.describe_stack = function(req, res){
         AWS.config.update(awscred);
       var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();

        var params = {
          'StackName': 'demostack'
        };

        cloudformation.describeStacks(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              res.send(err);
          } else {
              res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        });

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That *404 Not Found* response tends to suggest that the stack that you're looking for, `demostack`, does not exist or is not running or could possibly be in a different region, ensure that the stack exists in the region `ap-southeast-1`.

As you can see at the docs for [DescribeStacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStacks.html) this only returns data for running stacks if specified by `StackName`.

Therefore I'd use the following code in your file above to [ListStacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListStacks.html) and confirm that the stack is running and has the name you expect to see.

```
exports.list_stacks = function(req, res) {
    AWS.config.update(awscred);
    var cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation();

    cloudformation.listStacks({}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });

}
```

As a side note, I'd not post any real Secret Access keys here!